# packrat not bundling all files

Tags: r, packrat

I have developed several shiny applications on a development server. To aid with deployment to our production server I've written a function that uses packrat's bundle function to bundle up the application. My function then sftps the bundle to the production server and then sends a command over ssh to call packrat::unbundle() on the production server.

When I first wrote this it all seemed to work but a few months, maybe a year, ago it started messing up. It would report that the app was restored on production but the app wouldn't open on the production server. When I would look at the directory for the app it would not include all the files associated with the application. When I open the bundle on the development server it does not contain all the files that should be there. What would cause packrat::bundle() to not include all the files in the bundled directory? For example, the bundle contains the packrat folder, the .Rproj file, one of two associated .csv data files, and a restart.txt file, but does not contain ui.R, server.R, global.R, or one .csv file. It isn't always consistently wrong, every great once in a while it works fine... I am very confused... any help or insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The webpage says: "Need help?
Drop by packrat-discuss and let us know if you have any questions or comments."

Comment: Good idea, it didn't even occur to me to ask on google groups. I always just immediately go to stackoverflow. I've posted the question there as well. Thanks